# fix php parameter called intl extension during prestashop installation

Tags: php, installation, prestashop

I am going to install Prestashop. When the system compatibility step is under the required PHP parameters header, an error is displayed saying "Intl extension is not loaded." Can anyone help me fix this?
i am using php 7.4.28  version

Comment: You need to install the extension **php-intl**, then you should add or uncomment line **extension=intl** in php.ini.

Comment: Close vote because this question is about installing PrestaShop and not about coding. It belongs to SuperUser instead.